# Loop error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to display all posts in Post table with say id=5 ......

controller

```
user_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController

# other methods are also present...

  def profile
    uid=session[:userid]  #session contains userid,it is stored in uid....Eg:5
    @post=Post.find_by_userid(uid) #Display all posts with userid=5 in Post table.
  end

end
```

view

```
profile.html.erb

    <h1>In Profile</h1>
    <%=session[:test]%>
    <% @post.each do |p|%>
    <%= p.title%>
    <%= p.body%>
    <%= p.tag%> 
    <%end%>
```

when i execute i get an error like....
Showing /Users/Vineeth/QA4/app/views/users/profile.html.erb where line #3 raised:undefined method `each' for #

Please help me fix the error......thanks.

Comment: `undefined method 'each' for` # what?

Comment: undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x007fc0cb6441a8>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.find_by_userid(uid)` is same as `Post.where(:userid => uid).first`, return only one record.

You should use `Post.where(:userid => uid)`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Post.find_by_user(uid)` which is not something you can iterate over. It only returns a single record.

Use something that returns a collection, like `Post.where(:userid => uid)`